# How to prevent the phone from losing IP traffic?

Tags: android, 3g

I have a simple app that periodically sends HTTP_GET requests to a server. When sending requests over 3G, I noticed that the requests sometimes time out (and the server-side logging shows that it NEVER receives the request either).

After trying out different combinations I found one consistant pattern when this problem occures (it times out after every 5-15 successful requests).

```
- TelephonyRegistry: notifyDataConnection() state=2isDataConnectivityPossible()true, reason=null
 - TelephonyRegistry: broadcastDataConnectionStateChanged() state=CONNECTEDtypes=default supl, interfaceName=rmnet0
 - NetworkLocationProvider: onDataConnectionStateChanged 3
```

According to Google, NetworkLocationProvider is changed to 'DATA_SUSPENDED', which implies "connection is up, but IP traffic is temporarily unavailable". (see [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#DATA_SUSPENDED)). On the situations where HTTP_GET requests succeeds, the state is changed to '8'. My app doesn't use the location manage and I've shut down every other non-critical app from running!

I want to know:

1. What is the cause of this issue? Why does the connection status go to DATA_SUSPENDED?
2. Is it possible to avoid/overcome this problem?

Any help/insight into this is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the rate of these connections? Are we talking like 15 connection attempts in 1 ms?

Comment: Each HTTP_GET request was approximately 10 seconds apart, and was on a HTC Hero running Android 2.1

Comment: Is it possible you are just in an area where you get really poor signal?

Comment: The 3G signal strength is high (according to the notification bar), and never experienced any drop calls/issues with surfing the net using the browser etc. At the moment, I am looking into see if this is a HTC Sense related issue or not using a Nexus One.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my app running on an Huawei IDEOS X3 with Android 2.3.5. The app sends data each minute to a server using HttpClient.

Using logcat I can see that the data connection is lost and then reestablished after a short while. Previously my app stopped working since it tried to send data without a connection causing an exception which was not properly handed.

I don't know the reason for the intermittently dropped data connection but I now handle the situation by checking if there is a data connection prior to sending the data. In my case it does not matter if some data is never sent. If it was important to avoid data loss, I could buffer the data and send it once the connection was back.

```
public Boolean isDataConnection() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED;
}
```